# python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled is not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this in my setting.json:

```
"python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
"python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
```

Pytest discovery is working, I can see and run pytest tests in the VS Code test window. But when I save it doesn't run my tests.

I test this by changing the name of a method that would cause 80% of my tests to fail and save and nothing happens - I'm expecting to see a test run, get an error, etc.

Test discovery and everything is working fine but it's just not running the tests on save.

Comment: the test **discovery** is for tests in the test files that are saved. Which tests are written and should/could be run. You describe test **run** on save.

Comment: It only runs when I modify and save a _test_ your saying? Is there a setting to run all unit tests when the project is saved?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late reply, but still, I believe there is a solution.

As it was mentioned in the comments to the question `python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled` enables automatic test *discovery* on save. However, the latest version of [Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter) supports automatic execution of test suites.
The feature was added in https://github.com/kondratyev-nv/vscode-python-test-adapter/issues/193.

After installing the extension see if your tests are correctly discovered and then you can make your test to execute automatically.
To enable autorun, right-click on a test suite and select "Enable autorun". After that, any changes to files in a workspace will re-execute tests when files are saved. See the example below.
[image: Autorun example]

You can also enable autorun for all tests by clicking on three dots in the Test explorer UI bar.